# How do I fix a "red flag" regarding my SSN on my credit file?

Tags: united-states, credit-report

According to the agent I talked to in myFICO.com, the reason I've been having so much trouble trying to get my credit report is because there is some kind of a problem with my SSN in my credit file. She suggested that I call all three of the agencies to attempt to rectify the problem.

The problem is, I can't seem to find any phone numbers for these agencies that isn't automated! Can anyone point me towards the right number to call when you have problems with your credit file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found this:

http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20060827082656AAXbnY5
also http://gethuman.com/us/print.html

**Experian** 800‑493‑1058 TBD

**Equifax** 866‑640‑2273 Press 3 0.

**TransUnion** 800‑916‑8800 Press 2 at each prompt.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! I'm waiting on what they say regarding my mail-in request, but this will definitely help!